# angular directive with controllerAs dosn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

I'm struggling with making angular directive work with **controllerAs**. When using $scope everything work as expected but when get rid of $scope directive controller doesn't work. Please see the code below and plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o3F4lUrxL4mK1DWSYsad. Why the value is not displayed on button click?

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
    <button ng-click="test.buttonClick()">push me</button>
    <test-directive  datasource="test.current"></test-directive>
</div>
</body>

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('testDirective', function() {
        var controller = function() {
            console.log(this);

        };
        return {
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                datasource: '=',
            },
            template: '<div>{{vm.somekey}}</div>'
        }
    })
    .controller('TestCtrl', function() {
        var vm = this,
            current = {};

        vm.buttonClick = function() {
            console.log('buttonClick');
            vm.current = {
                somekey: 'somevalue'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It may not work because you don't have `vm.somekey` as you use in template, your controller defines `vm.current.somekey` instead but only after button is clicked. If you want to display value after template is loaded you should probably add `vm.somekey = 'somevalue'` after you initialize `vm`.

Comment: controllerAs concept is used to reduce the usage of scope. thereby you can use this.somekey = 'somevalue' in your controller instead of using scope.somekey = 'somevalue'

Comment: It's only working with @michał-sałaciński change: "vm.datasource.somekey"

Comment: Hi change your template to '<div>{{vm.datasource.somekey}}</div>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be rather:  [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/cV1ARNqUrr9G60cPek6t?p=preview)

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('testDirective', function() {
    var controller = function() {
      console.log(this);

    };
    return {
      controller: controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        datasource: '=',
      },
      template: '<div>{{vm.datasource.somekey}}</div>'
    }
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this,
      current = {};

    vm.buttonClick = function() {
      console.log('buttonClick');
      vm.current = {
        somekey: 'somevalue'
      }
    }
  });
```

Just changed "vm.datasource.somekey"